# Scanning unknown set of characters

Tags: c, scanf

What is the correct way to scan unknown number of set of characters? let me explain , i want to scan with form "char:integer" e.g a:5 
What is the right way

```
while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) != EOF){...}
```

or

```
while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) ==3){...}
```

the second pattern is tricky bcs    sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

also why does in first pattern using windows require ctr+Z (eof) to press twice?

Comment: Your question is contradictory.Are scanning an unknown input stream or scanning char:int?

Comment: There is nothing unknown about what you are trying to scan . You are scanning char char int

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` must be the first keyboard entry after a `newline` and also be followed by a `newline`.

Comment: Safest way is read the whole line with `fgets()` and then use `strto`*something*() to grab the integer value.

Comment: In terminals, there is a special way for having an EOF in the input stream, but if there's already input to be read, it will be consumed along with that input. So therefore for the EOF will be noticed when there is no prior input already buffered.

Answer (score 1):

> the second pattern is tricky bcs sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

That's because

```
while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) == 3){...}
```

will run only when all the three variables got assigned properly without any early matching failure or end of file.

Whereas

```
while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) != EOF){...}
```

will run even if few (<3) variables got assigned unless there's an end of file. That means this definition will work even in the case of matching failure which is undesirable.

So use `while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) == 3){...}` this definition.

Comment: while(scanf(" %c%c%d",&a,&b,&c) == 3){...} it seems that while loop does not ened even if i only input new line.

Comment: @Johnyb That's because `%d` in `scanf` ignores all white spaces in the input and waits till it finds the non-whitespace character in the input. When you entered a multiple newlines then first two of them got assigned to `a` and `b` but the `%d` is still waiting for the non-whitespace char to occur. If you only entered a single newline then that got assigned to `a` and `%c`, `%d` are still waiting for the input since they haven't seen end of file yet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just use `while(scanf("%c:%d",&a,&b) ==2){...}`.

Because this will stop the loop when a matching failure **or** EOF is met, both of which implies there happenes something unexpected, so you'd better jump out of the loop immediately. And I don't think the value of `':'` is useful.